# Copy doesn't work on DataGrid templated columns?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, copy

When working with templated column in WPF datagrid, you cann't copy cell content anymore, does anyone knows how this can be solved?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to set the `ClipboardContentBinding` property to the desired property in the row item, see the following code:

```
<DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding YouProperty}">

            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: what if we want same for a textbox inside a Grid      <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"   BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>